# addObject replaces all the previous objects in NSMutableArray

Tags: objective-c

In my IOS app, I have two view controllers. ControllerA and ControllerB. I have an array of objects in ControllerA. ControllerB creates a new Object and adds it to the array in ControllerA. I do this with a reference to the array and pass that to ControllerB. I add a new object in ControllerB, but when I move back to ControllerA, the array has the right size, but all of the contents are the same.
The array is of type Group.

What do you think the issue is?

Code that adds object in controllerB:

```
NSString *groupName = userName.text; //gets value from UITextField
NSString *pword = password.text;
Group *newgroup = [[Group alloc]init:groupName :pword]; //init values are just NSString's in a class called Group
[groups addObject:newgroup];
[ViewController print];
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Comment: Sounds like you are adding the same object repeatedly, rather than a new object each time.

Comment: Yeah, but I create a new object each time the object is added into the array, so I have no idea why I keep getting this problem.

Comment: Show all the code that inserts into this array.

Comment: It's good thing, If you add the code use to past information between controller.